# HTML display resolution

Tags: html, css

I have been looking at @media on [this](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/advanced/mediaqueries/) site and tried doing this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1350px;)
{
    #td6img{margin-left:400px;}
}
```

I am pretty sure the default resolution is 1360px, when I resize the window the image does not seem to move but stay in the same place. Here is the CSS for the image before the resizing

```
#td6img
{
    display:block;
    margin-left:410px;
}
```

The CSS does not seem to change upon resizing. I don't know if I set the width to too much or if I'm doing something wrong with the `@media`

What would I use to move the position of the image? I am trying to do this to other elements also, not just this one.

Comment: You could use css framework like Bootstrap for responsive design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a simple media query:

```
img {
  width: 200px;
  @media (min-width:800px) {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

In this example, the `img`, by default, will be `200px` wide. When the screen width reaches `800px`, the image will resize to `400px`. This a "mobile-first" approach, because the default CSS caters to smaller devices.

---

For your example, if you have an element `#td6img`, you can change the margin the following way.

```
#td6img {
  margin-left: 410px;
  @media (min-width: 1350px) {
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
}
```

This changes `margin-left` when the screen width gets to `1350px` and up. Otherwise, the the `margin-left` value will be `410px`.

Note that unless you are targeting an element with Javascript, it is generally bad practice to use id`s for elements. You should use classes instead.

Comment: What is the difference from targetting a single element than a class? I just want to style that one element, and there is not a child of it. If you are saying to have the parent in a class element, I have multiple images that I want with different CSS.

Comment: ids are singletons, and can only be used once per page. As your page grows, you'll find that better code takes advantage of using class elements multiple times over. Even if it doesn't, there is no *harm* in applying a class name that you don't reuse. But if you want to a later point, you can!

Although the names "class" and "id" seem to indicate that one should be used for general styling of similar elements, and the other should be used for selecting specific, singleton elements, it's not the case in the broader practice of web development.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon (`;`) in your media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1350px)
{
    #td6img{margin-left:400px;}
}
```

Comment: thank you, by the way, do you know what the screen resolution is for the width? Is it 1360px or 1400px?

Comment: @JarFile I'm not sure what you mean. Media queries can target any width you want. If you want to know the width of a device, you can use JavaScript or the inspector of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

First off you should remove the semicolon from your media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
    #td6img { margin-left: 400px; }
}
```

You can also use your browser's inspector to determine the size of your browser's viewport. 1350px is pretty large, so make sure your viewport is in fact that big. Also, it looks like the element moves only 10px on reaching that breakpoint, which may be difficult to notice.